# Can law enforcements from country(A) request or force an isp or a company from country(B) handover its logs?

Tags: internet

If someone hacks a server from country(A) using a vpn from country(B), law enforcements from country(A) must obtain logs from the vpn company or the vpn isp from country(B) inorder  to find the person of interest, how a case like this is handled, can law enforcements force the vpn company or the vpn isp to hand over the logs?

Comment: Anyone can *request* them to hand over the logs.

Comment: See also wikipedia: [Mutual legal assistance treaty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_legal_assistance_treaty).